# adb push command takes too long

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to check my app on AVD with api 16. when I press on run button in Android Studio it takes about 6 minutes to push the apk file to the emulator.

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.1.